# Please how do I disable eslint errors being injected into my webpage by webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, eslint

Am using the vue webpack project template and while the dev server is running, any encountered errors get injected into my webpage and also displayed in the browser console. I guess this is the expected behavior but I would like to turn off the one injected into the dom in order to use jquery and bootstrap's Javascript since it appears they don't follow some eslint rules.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `.eslintrc.js` in your Vue project and there you can disable/add some rules. If you want to ignore everything (which is not recommended) - you can add to `.eslintignore` `src/*.js` at the bottom.

BTW, what is the point of using jQuery with Vue?

Comment: some vue plugins require jquery. especially the ones that are wrappers for 3rd party apps.